# How do I select all movies with five or more actors in a many-to-many movies and actors relationship?

Tags: mysql

If I have a movie table, an actor table, and a movie_actor table, how do I select all movies with five or more actors? All I can do is an inner join on the table but this will return all results, not just the results with five or more actors.

Thanks!

Comment: `HAVING COUNT` is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  m.movie_name
from
  movies as m
left join
  actors as a
on
  m.movie_id = a.movie_id
group by
  m.movie_name
having
  count(*) >= 5;
```